# Spark 2.4 : How to create custom encoder for type List?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

We have a requirement to use custom encoders in our spark job.
Currently we are using custom encoders for simple Object types or for Tuples (i.e. Tuple2, Tuple3, Tuple4).

Now we need to create custom encoder for a Scala List as well.

We tried following(but this gives compilation error):

```
implicit def list[List](implicit c: Encoder[List]): Encoder[List] = Encoders.kryo[List](c)
```

Following gives run time exception:

```
implicit def list[List[A]](implicit c: ClassTag[List]): Encoder[List] = 
Encoders.kryo[List](c)
```

We also tried following (but no luck):

```
 class RowKey[S,A](val i: S,
                        val s: List[Tuple2[String, java.util.ArrayList[A]]])

  // alias for the type to convert to and from
  type RowKeyEncoder[S,A] = (S, List[Tuple2[String, java.util.ArrayList[A]]])

  // implicit conversions
  implicit def toEncoded[S,A](o: RowKey[S,A]): RowKeyEncoder[S,A] = (o.i, o.s)
  implicit def fromEncoded[S,A](e: RowKeyEncoder[S,A]): RowKey[S,A] =
    new RowKey[S,A](e._1, e._2)
```

Schema of our dataset is as below:

```
(String, List[Tuple2[String, java.util.ArrayList[A]]])
```

Any pointers will be of great help.

Thanks

Anuj

Comment: what is the data format being processed?

Answer (score 0):

You were close with this approach:

```scala
implicit def list[List[A]](implicit c: ClassTag[List]): Encoder[List] = Encoders.kryo[List](c)
```

The problem here is on the `classTag` in which you are not using `List[A]` but `List` which only matches `List[Nothing]`.

Try with this:

```scala
implicit def listEncoder[A](implicit c: ClassTag[List[A]]): Encoder[List[A]] = Encoders.kryo[List[A]](c)
```

In this case your type parameter is `A` and you pass it to your `ClassTag` as `List[A]`.